# I am trying to check whether the password input fiels of the two field are same or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have tried the Jquery and Javascript as well nothing wrk. Please tell me what need to be done, If I Click on submit Button then the password of the two input fields must be compared and checked.

```
<div class="registration-details">
    <input type="text" name="Name" maxlength="30" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required runat="server" />
    <input type="email"name="Email" required placeholder="Enter Your Email Address" runat="server"  />
    <input type="text" name="Number" required placeholder="Enter Your Contact Number" maxlength="10" />

    <input type="text" name="AddressLine1" placeholder="Address Line 1" maxlength="50" required />
    <input type="text" name="AddressLine2" placeholder="Address line 2" maxlength="50" />

    <input type="password" name="Password" required placeholder="Enter Password" />
    <input type="password" name="ConfirmPassword" required placeholder="Confirm Password" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
</div>
```

```js
$('#form').submit(function() {
    var id1 = $(#Password).text();
    var id2 = $(#ConfirmPassword).text();
    if (id1 == id2) {
        alert('Error, cant do that');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: use .val() instead of .text(), and use ID's or class's

Answer (score 3):

Try below code:

**1.add Ids to input fields:**

```
<input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" required placeholder="Enter Password" />
<input type="password" id="ConfirmPassword" name="ConfirmPassword" required placeholder="Confirm Password" />
```

**2. check in jquery**

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    var id1 = $("#Password").val(); // use .val()
    var id2 = $("#ConfirmPassword").val();
    if (id1 == id2) {
        alert('Error, cant do that');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect syntax in your code:

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    var id1 = $("#Password").val); //this is the right syntax
    var id2 = $("#ConfirmPassword").val();//this too
    if (id1 == id2) {
        alert('Error, cant do that');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

As other users have rightly mentioned:

`.text()` is for elements containing text, it won't work on input elements.

`.val()` is to obtain input element texts.

Answer (score 0):

missing form tag and 
missing id in password

try this

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("hi");
  
$('form').submit(function() {
    var id1 = $('#Password').val();
    var id2 = $('#ConfirmPassword').val();
    if (id1 == id2) {
        alert('Error, cant do that');
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
  
  });
```

```html
<div class="registration-details">
  <form action="#" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="Name" maxlength="30" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required runat="server" />
    <input type="email"name="Email" required placeholder="Enter Your Email Address" runat="server"  />
    <input type="text" name="Number" required placeholder="Enter Your Contact Number" maxlength="10" />

    <input type="text" name="AddressLine1" placeholder="Address Line 1" maxlength="50" required />
    <input type="text" name="AddressLine2" placeholder="Address line 2" maxlength="50" />

    <input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" required placeholder="Enter Password" />
    <input type="password" id="ConfirmPassword"  name="ConfirmPassword" required placeholder="Confirm Password" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  alert("hi"); 

After adding this in the code, my page is showing blank.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnsubmit").on('click', function(){
      var password=$('#password').val();
       var confirmpassword=$('#confirmpassword').val();
      if(password == confirmpassword)
        {
          alert('Password and confirm password are Equal');
        }
      else
        {
           alert('Password and confirm password are not Equal');
        }
    });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="registration-details">
    <input type="text" name="Name" maxlength="30" placeholder="Enter Your Name" required runat="server" /><br/>
    <input type="email"name="Email" required placeholder="Enter Your Email Address" runat="server"  /><br/>
    <input type="text" name="Number" required placeholder="Enter Your Contact Number" maxlength="10" /><br/>

    <input type="text" name="AddressLine1" placeholder="Address Line 1" maxlength="50" required /><br/>
    <input type="text" name="AddressLine2" placeholder="Address line 2" maxlength="50" /><br/>

    <input type="password" id="password" name="Password" required placeholder="Enter Password" /><br/>
    <input type="password" id="confirmpassword"  name="ConfirmPassword" required placeholder="Confirm Password" /><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="btnsubmit" name="Submit" />
</div>
```